# debugger skip in httpclient.getasync in xamarin without error

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I want to connect to my Web api with these code
but when debugger arrived on

> `var response = await client.GetAsync(url);`

skip without any error,

***UPDATE***

it's mean:

[image]

I set breakpoint and when debugger arrive on that line after that don't catch the next line and exit from this block and jump to caller method

```
 public class Constants
{
    public const string BaseUrl = "https://localhost:44301/";
}
```

2:

```
    public static class GeneralUrl
{
    public static string ComapnyNameUrl()
    {
        return string.Format(Constants.BaseUrl);
    }
}
```

3: change to 3.1

```
 public async static Task<List<CompanyName>> GetCompanyNamesAsync()
    {
        List<CompanyName> companyNameList = new List<CompanyName>();
        string url = GeneralUrl.ComapnyNameUrl() + "api/CompanyName";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content =await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                companyNameList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompanyName>>(content);
            }


        }
        return companyNameList;
    }
```

***UPDATE 2***

3.1:

I change above code to this but the problen exist
Update

```
public class CompanyNameService
{
    private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public async static Task<List<CompanyName>> GetCompanyNamesAsync()
    {
        List<CompanyName> companyNameList = new List<CompanyName>();
        string url = GeneralUrl.ComapnyNameUrl() + "api/Companyname";

            var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content =await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                companyNameList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompanyName>>(content);
            }
        return companyNameList;
    }
 
}
```

also my startup.cs in my web api is

```
   services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o =>
        {
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 0;
         });
          services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
  options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
   Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

***END OF UPDATE 2***

and final for calling them is=>

4:

```
  protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var companyName = await CompanyNameService.GetCompanyNamesAsync();
    }
```

I think that it was for async method what is my mistake??

***UPDATE***

In debug mode in output windows I have this message

> 02-10 13:04:21.568 I/Choreographer(  790): Skipped 428 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> 02-10 13:04:21.642 I/OpenGLRenderer(  790): Davey! duration=7213ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=51372290598463, Vsync=51379423931511, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=51379430268200, AnimationStart=51379430347200, PerformTraversalsStart=51379430673700, DrawStart=51379441519600, SyncQueued=51379446948700, SyncStart=51379447122900, IssueDrawCommandsStart=51379447270300, SwapBuffers=51379483411800, FrameCompleted=51379504170100, DequeueBufferDuration=409000, QueueBufferDuration=612000,

***UPDATE 3:***

As I try use local address, after more than 5 min got a message in out put window that  "the operation in canceled" and catch the exception with the same ***message***.

Comment: debugger skip on 'var response = await client.GetAsync(url);'  without any error

Comment: yes, I clean my project many times, and re write my code many times

Comment: try this HttpClient webClient = new HttpClient();
                webClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(GeneralUrl.ComapnyNameUrl());
 HttpResponseMessage response = await webClient.GetAsync("api/carmodel");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                { etc.

Comment: @sunny Could you please elaborate what did you mean by *debugger skip without any error*?

Comment: @JKC i update  my code with your code but result is the same as before.

Comment: @peter-Csala I update my Code

Comment: @sunny Have you tried to remove `using` around `HttpClient`? By the way it is [anti-pattern](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: @PeterCsala now i remove but is the same and I update my question

Comment: @sunny It might seem silly but are you able to call the api from a browser?

Comment: @PeterCsala yes its possible, I think I have problem in 2 point 1. in sync methods or 2. in htts config in my xamarin project, I try to resole all of them but it confuse me,

Comment: in Out put windows after debug I have this message:  02-13 22:41:37.445 I/Choreographer(27382): Skipped 303 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-13 22:41:37.508 I/OpenGLRenderer(27382): Davey! duration=5114ms; Flags=0,

Comment: I create Apk from my project and  install on my phone, it work fine, but doesn't work on emulator . I reinstall windows and VS 2019 it work fine but after 2 days it happened again, how can I resolve that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var companyName = await GetCompanyNamesAsync();
    }

    public async static Task<List<CompanyName>> GetCompanyNamesAsync()
    {
        List<CompanyName> companyNameList = new List<CompanyName>();
        string url = GeneralUrl.ComapnyNameUrl() + "api/Companyname";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {

            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
         
            
            companyNameList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CompanyName>>(response);


        }

        return companyNameList;
    }
```

Comment: I do that but not working, I know that my problem is in asyc methods, but I don't know where/

Comment: Try to change the `localhost` to the ip address in your url.